# Math.random() problems in method

Tags: java, methods, random, compiler-errors

this might not be the hardest thing to acheive, yet I'm still having problems :S:

In my little program I'm simulating a card game (http://tinyurl.com/pf9fhf4) and I need to generate a random number from the range [0,35] in increments of 5. Ergo, the possible values should be : 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35.
I've tried this in a sepparate class first like this:

```
class RandomValue {
public static void main (String [] args){

int i =0;

    do {
    int n = (int) (Math.random()*36 );
        if (n%5 ==0){
        System.out.println(n);
        i++;
        }

    } while (i <1); 
  }
}
```

And this works!!!

When I tried making a method that would return this generated value :

```
public class Tarot {

public static int rValue (){

int i =0;

    do {
    int n = (int) (Math.random()*36 );
        if (n%5 ==0){
        int r =n;
        i++;
        }       
    }while(i<1);
    return r;   
  }
}
```

it returns an error:

```
Tarok.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            return r;
                   ^
```

What am I doing wrong, any suggestions how to do this in a more pretty way?

Comment: read up on variable scope: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/4/lec/08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this code

```
public class Tarot {

public static int rValue (){

int i =0;

    do {
    int n = (int) (Math.random()*36 );
        if (n%5 ==0){
        int r =n;
        i++;
        }       
    }while(i<1);
    return r;   
  }
}
```

to

```
public class Tarot {

public static int rValue (){

int i =0;
int r =0
    do {
    int n = (int) (Math.random()*36 );
        if (n%5 ==0){
        r=n;
        i++;
        }       
    }while(i<1);
    return r;   
  }
}
```

**reason**

The scope of variable `r` is within `if` loop So when trying to return r compiler did not find r

Answer (score 2):

`r` is known only in the scope of the `if`:

```
if (n%5 ==0) {
    int r =n;  //r is known only between the braces of the if
    i++;
} 
//I know r here said no one ever
```

Declare `r` outside the scope of the `if`.

I highly recommend you to indent your code for clarity and possible bug prevention.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to just generate numbers divisible by 5:

```
public static int rValue() {
    return Random.nextInt(8) * 5;
}
```

Comment: So if I want my range of result I do this:
     return Random.nextInt(36) * 5;
??

Comment: No, it works like I stated it. `nextInt(8)` gives you integers from 0 to 7 and after multiplication by 5 the only possible results are 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35

Answer (score 0):

Hello you are defining your "r" variable inside of the while loop scope, but trying to return it inside of the method scope. So just move your "r" variable definition to the begining of method as you do for "i".

Answer (score 0):

`r` variable is not defined, and `return` statement can't see it.
Try to make so:

```
int r = 0;
do {
int n = (int) (Math.random()*36);
    if (n%5 == 0){
    r = n;
    i++;
    }       
} while(i < 1);
return r;
```

And for what do you use this? U tryed to find first random number, that share out for 5